# Single source for both .ssh/config and /etc/hosts

Tags: ssh, hosts

I'm looking for a DRY solution that would allow me both

```
ssh server-alias
```

and

```
ping server-alias
```

I know the former is reading `.ssh/config`, and the latter `/etc/hosts`, but I'd rather not repeat the same aliases in both files. Is it a good idea to have a single source for both? If so, how can I accomplish it?

I can simply omit `HostName` line from the `.ssh/config` entry, and it will be read from `/etc/hosts`, does this approach have any disadvantages? If so, what should I use instead? It's intended for a single-user laptop, and no host masking is required.

Comment: both files serve different purpose. you can build (update/patch) one or the other with sed/awk magic easilly, but remember that ~/.ssh/config can be in every users' home (including possible future users), an it can be actually used for "masking" real hosts. e.g. Host *.com, Hostname fake.example.edu...

Comment: Thanks, it's intended for a single-user laptop, and no masking is required.

Comment: Searching for "best practices" is usually "opinion based". If you use `ssh_config` for aliases only, the `/etc/hosts` will do the same job. So what is the actual problem?

Comment: Edited the "best practice" part. I hope the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is no need to clutter your .ssh/config with Hostnames if all you want is tab expansion.

Entries in /etc/hosts will be sufficient.

.ssh/config is for specifying login names etc.

Maybe you should use wildcards in your hostnames in .ssh/config if you really want to specify connection details there at all.

http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config